# Why won't the form value show up?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am creating a simple form, and I want to write to the console the value of the input once the form has been submitted and successfully validated. However, when I go to test my current progress, I input a random piece of text and nothing shows up, even in the console. Here is the code I have now (excluding any commented out code):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script language="Javascript">
      window.onload = function() { // So the DOM can be defined
        function validateForm() {
          var form = document.forms['encrypt']['text'];
          if(form == "") {
            alert("Enter piece of text to encrypt");
            return false;
          } else {
            console.log(form.value);
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="encrypt" action="#" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
      Text: <input type="text" name="text">
      <input type="submit" name="Submit and Encrypt!">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Even when I type nothing and submit the form, the alert doesn't pop up. There was other posts related to form problems, but they don't have any relation to mine. Is there something wrong with my code? What is the problem and how can I fix it?

**Edit:** I realized `window.onload` only executes the code inside of it when the window is loading. After that, all functions cease to exist. In addition to removing the `onload` handler, I had to relocate the validation function within the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your validateForm function is only visible within your onload function. Additionally, you were comparing the form to an empty string, not the value within the text field in the form. The console.log would also not have been visible, because the page refreshes before you can see it.

Below is the code with those three things fixed.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script>
      function validateForm() {
        var text = document.forms['encrypt']['text'].value;
        if(text == "") {
          alert("Enter piece of text to encrypt");
          return false;
        } else {
          alert("Entered '" + text + "', refreshing now.");
          return true;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="encrypt" action="#" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
      Text: <input type="text" name="text">
      <input type="submit" name="Submit and Encrypt!">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that set `document.forms` to `null`?

Comment: Sorry, which line do you mean by "that"?

Comment: You dropped the `window.onload` handler and deep within that, I reference the form with `document.forms`. It's the first line inside of the `validateForm()` declaration.

Comment: I'm glad, high-five :-)

Comment: Now I can encrypt submitted text and display it!

Comment: I can use `alert()` and keep the result on there, but if I use a paragraph, it flashes for like half a second and disappears. What does that mean?

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to wrap this function in an `onload` event handler.  And doing so is limiting the scope of the function definition so that the code which tries to call it can't actually see it.  (That is, after `onload` completes, the function you defined is no longer in scope and ceases to exist.)

Just remove the handler and define the function directly:

```
<script language="Javascript">
    function validateForm() {
      var form = document.forms['encrypt']['text'];
      if(form == "") {
        alert("Enter piece of text to encrypt");
        return false;
      } else {
        console.log(form.value);
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I think that will set `document.forms` to `null`. Let me try it.

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue: This function doesn't *set* `document.forms` to anything, it just *reads* from it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your function validateForm() is not accessible in the scope when you click the submit. You can verify this by call this function in the console.
In your code, it's defined inside the window.onload, so please move the function out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `window.onload = function() {` and just keep the `validateForm` function.